# How to bind a label inside a gridview to another table?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a very standard `Gridview`, with Edit and Delete buttons auto-generated.
It is bound to a `tableadapter` which is linked to my `RelationshipTypes` table.

```
dbo.RelationshipTypes:
ID, Name, OriginConfigTypeID, DestinationConfigTypeID
```

I wish to use a label that will pull the name from the `ConfigTypes` table, using the `OriginConfigTypeID` and `DestinationTypeID` as the link.

```
dbo.ConfigTypes:
ID, Name
```

My problem is, I can't automatically generate Edit and Delete buttons using an `Inner Join` in my dataset. Or can I?

Here is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" CssClass="TableList"
        DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="dsRelationShipTypes1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"
                SortExpression="ID" Visible=False/>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Origin" SortExpression="OriginCIType_ID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList Enabled=true ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsCIType1"
                        DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("OriginCIType_ID") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    &nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OriginCIType_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Destination" SortExpression="DestinationCIType_ID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsCIType1" DataTextField="Name"
                        DataValueField="ID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("DestinationCIType_ID") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DestinationCIType_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

So I did try to create my own edit and delete buttons, but kept receiving the error

> "cannot find update method"

or something similar.  Do I have to manually code the delete and update methods in my code-behind?

Comment: To "auto generate" the edit and delete button the gridview's associated  datasource must have an Update query and a Delete query defined in it's markup or via code behind.  `Update`s and `Delete`s are going to require a primary key, usually defined by the Gridviews `DatakeyNames` property which end up being passed to the their respective query parameters along with any bound fields.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell either the ObjectDataSource what object to use or the SQLDataSource what stored proc to use.  Use the "UpdateMethod" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code behind technique to mention about what are the method that could handle the update and delete function. This is the standard way to do that. You can either use the Sqldatasorce to describe the source.You can mention which all the tables used for inner join and can also use the sql query.